# Downloading a file using JWK for Authentication

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, xmlhttprequest, jwk

[This article](https://auth0.com/blog/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/) states that:

> When using cookies, you can trigger a file download and stream the contents easily. However, in the tokens world, where the request is done via XHR, you can't rely on that.

Is there something tricky about downloading a file using XHR from a URL that requires a JWK token for authorization?

Comment: A JWK is just a key, there is no JWK Token. In any case, except the authentication method (if any) there is no notable difference between a file download done through a XHR or a direct call

Comment: That's what I figured too and hence the surprise when I read the article.  Any idea what it's trying to convey?  It seems simple.  If the file is protected, put the key/token in the Authorization bearer header and get access to the file and use XHR to stream the download....?  Have not actually done it yet, so just trying to see whether there's something I'm missing.